# Kotlin / Android Studio - How can I pass a variable from an override fun to the rest of the app?

Tags: android, android-studio, variables, kotlin, global-variables

I have looked around a bit, and have found no good answer to my problem. On my app, I've got a timer. This timer stops on a click, and I would like to calculate a score based on the time left. I can use the "millisUntilFinished" to calculate the score, but I can't reused the score variable in my app. Could you please help me with the correct / best way to do this ? Below, my code:

```
var score: Long

        val timer = object : CountDownTimer(20000, 1000) {
        override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long)  {
            timer.setText("" + millisUntilFinished / 1000)
              score = millisUntilFinished / 1000
            }
            override fun onFinish() {
            timer.setText("0");
        }
    }
    timer.start()
```

When I try to use it later in my app, I get a "*Variable 'score' must be initialized.*" I've tried quite a few things but every time I end up not being able to reuse a variable initialized in an override fun.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Format the code please

Comment: It could well be that your timer hasn't ticked before you attempt to access score, so score has never been initialized. This code won't even compile as you don't initialize score in the first place either, so no idea how you're getting a run time exception...

Comment: Shouldn't you set an initial value for score? `var score: Lang = 0` or so?

Comment: In general, you want to avoid global variables in any code you write. I don't know what your experience is but you should soon start looking at _design pattern_ like _MVVM_ to understand how to move data in your app. 

You can also use a _listener_

Now, if you do really want to have a global variable, look what at _static variables_ and the _Singleton_ pattern. But I'll reiterate, this is in general a bad idea to use them, unless you know exactly what you do.

Comment: @VadimCaen That's a nonsensical suggestion given the small amount of code we're shown.  Having class level state variables is extremely common-  these are unlikely to be truly global.  Your suggestion has nothing to do with his question and isn't actually based on the code as posted.

Comment: My answer solved your problem?

Comment: @MohammadMoeinGolchin yes perfect ! Thanks a lot. The second option worked perfectly !

Comment: @MohammadMoeinGolchin "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score." 
=> A bit to new to this community ;)

Comment: @GabeSechan, nonsensical is a little harsh. I assumed that OP or other readers of this question will be new to Android and wanted to give so starting points to help them dive deeper into understanding how to move data in an Android application. I agree that this doesn't answer the question, this is why I made a comment an not an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may define it as `lateinit var` or you should initialize it.

```
lateinit var score: Long

        val timer = object : CountDownTimer(20000, 1000) {
        override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long)  {
            timer.setText("" + millisUntilFinished / 1000)
              score = millisUntilFinished / 1000
            }
            override fun onFinish() {
            timer.setText("0");
        }
    }
    timer.start()
```

Note that `lateinit` defines in class not in function.
Or you can use this:

```
var score=0.toLong()

        val timer = object : CountDownTimer(20000, 1000) {
        override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long)  {
            timer.setText("" + millisUntilFinished / 1000)
              score = millisUntilFinished / 1000
            }
            override fun onFinish() {
            timer.setText("0");
        }
    }
    timer.start()
```