# Kotlin Spring Boot Autowired lateinit issue with quartz scheduler class

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin, quartz-scheduler

I'm just implements quartz scheduler with kotlin and spring boot.

**kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property userController has not been initialized**

I know userController Object is not created with  @autowired basically in kotlin lateinit create object lazy so i d'not have idea to fix this issue. any possible way to create object in kotlin with eagerly to fix this issue

---

I'm Getting the following error:

```
Full Error Log : For reference


21:02:00.037 [DatabaseScheduler_Worker-1] ERROR org.quartz.core.JobRunShell - Job commentJobGroup.commentJob threw an unhandled Exception: 
kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property userController has not been initialized
    at com.lovevirus.kotlinQuartzScheduler.scheduler.Jobs.CommentJob.getUserController(CommentJob.kt:17)
    at com.lovevirus.kotlinQuartzScheduler.scheduler.Jobs.CommentJob.execute(CommentJob.kt:21)
    at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:202)
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:573)
21:02:00.038 [DatabaseScheduler_Worker-1] ERROR org.quartz.core.ErrorLogger - Job (commentJobGroup.commentJob threw an exception.
org.quartz.SchedulerException: Job threw an unhandled exception.
    at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:213)
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:573)
Caused by: kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property userController has not been initialized
    at com.lovevirus.kotlinQuartzScheduler.scheduler.Jobs.CommentJob.getUserController(CommentJob.kt:17)
    at com.lovevirus.kotlinQuartzScheduler.scheduler.Jobs.CommentJob.execute(CommentJob.kt:21)
    at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:202)
    ... 1 common frames omitted
```

Code:

```
import org.quartz.Job
import org.quartz.JobExecutionContext
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component
import com.lovevirus.kotlinQuartzScheduler.controller.UserController;
import org.slf4j.Logger
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired


@Component
class CommentJob : Job {
    private val logger: Logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CommentJob::class.java)
    @Autowired
    lateinit var userController : UserController;

    override fun execute(p0: JobExecutionContext?) {
      logger.debug("Inside Comment Job");
        userController.getUser();
       logger.debug("End Comment Job");
    }
}



Thanks in advance
```

Comment: What is UserController class?

Comment: It’s a controller call where business logic are available on this class

Comment: Why you have used lateinit? Use var instead of that

Comment: In Kotlin i'm not able to use var without lateinit. if i do that IDE Throws an error. I'm also done constructor injection also but it's not working

Comment: You should initialize it

Comment: And it depends to your UserController class

Comment: If i initialize like var usr:UserController = UserController() means UserController Method was called but inside the UserController also i have some Bean to Inject using @AutoWired lateinit so its throws an same error in UserController Class. I think Spring not Create a bean when i call the methos.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60926467/kotlin-android-studio-how-can-i-pass-a-variable-from-an-override-fun-to-the/60927069#60927069

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211525/discussion-between-sridhar-mca-and-mohammadmoeingolchin).

Answer (score 0):

Have you implemented a custom `SpringBeanJobFactory` that would allow dependency autowiring?

```
class AutowiringSpringBeanJobFactory : SpringBeanJobFactory(), ApplicationContextAware {

@Transient
private var beanFactory: AutowireCapableBeanFactory? = null

override fun setApplicationContext(applicationContext: ApplicationContext) {
    beanFactory = applicationContext.autowireCapableBeanFactory
}

override fun createJobInstance(bundle: TriggerFiredBundle): Any {
    val job = super.createJobInstance(bundle)
    beanFactory!!.autowireBean(job)
    return job
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The controller can also be passed on via the constructor:

```
@Component
class CommentJob(@Autowired userController: UserController): Job {

    private val logger: Logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CommentJob::class.java)
   
    override fun execute(p0: JobExecutionContext?) {
        logger.debug("Inside Comment Job");
        userController.getUser();
        logger.debug("End Comment Job");
    }
}
```

@Autowired can also be omitted. For more information about Kotlin and Spring Boot:

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-kotlin